# Returning NIL from a recursion in Lisp

Tags: lisp

I'm working on a problem in a book where I have a binary tree and I need to check if the sum of all the atoms on the left and right subtree are equal and if they're not, return nil. I managed to do it in two functions but when I try to do it in one I get an error because it tries to add a number to nil.

The code is

```
(defun foo (list)
   (cond ((null list) 0)
         ((atom list) list)
         ((/= (foo (cadr list))
              (foo (caddr list))) nil)
         ( T (+ (foo (car list))
                (foo (cdr list))))))
```

edit: the problem was two fold.

1) with the previous structure it would try to evaluate (cdr '(number)) so it would return null when it hit a list that looked like '(a (b c) d) since it would try to access (cdr '(d))

2) i used /= which only works if both arguments are numbers

The code that worked:

```
(defun foo (list)
  (cond ((null list) 0)
        ((atom list) list)
        ((null (cdr list)) (car list))
        ((null (equal(foo (cadr list)) (foo (caddr list)))) nil)
        (T (+ (car list)
              (foo (cadr list))
              (foo (caddr list))))))
```

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: Your specification is incomplete. As it's written now, you could satisfy it with `(defun foo (list) nil)`.

Comment: Since you can add only numbers, you need to check the result of FOO before you use it.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I don't think the problem was with adding numbers, i think the problem is my logic. Ideally it shouldn't have to add nil and a number because it should exit with nil and the implementation with two functions works because it goes down a limited level of the tree.

Comment: @melpomene I think you're right, I just can't seem to figure out how to get it to work or what else I should add.

Comment: @JohnSmith Does your edit mean you solved your problem? In that case, you could add an answer and mark your question as resolved when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that worked:

```
(defun foo (list)
  (cond ((null list) 0)
        ((atom list) list)
        ((null (cdr list)) (car list))
        ((null (equal(foo (cadr list)) (foo (caddr list)))) nil)
        (T (+ (car list)
              (foo (cadr list))
              (foo (caddr list))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

After having defined how you represent a binary tree, I mean the right subtree could be the cdr or the cadr, I would separate the two problems:

```
(defun sum-of-subtree (tree)
   (cond ((null tree) 0)
      ((atom tree) tree)
      (t (+ (sum-of-subtree (car tree))
            (sum-of-subtree (cdr tree))))))
(defun foo (tree)
   (cond ((null tree) t) ;or whatever you want
         ((atom tree) t)
         ((= (sum-of-subtree (car tree))
             (sum-of-subtree (cdr tree))) t)
         (t nil)))
```

Like that, you will not be confusing the value of the sum of the subtree with the comparison. Other languages have stronger typing, which avoids mixing the purposes of different functions

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm assuming your binary trees are lists of (val left-sub right-sub), which seems to match your code.

I'm not sure that there's a clean way to do that with recursion and a single function, since the recursive process (summing the left and right subtrees) is different from the value your function needs to return (whether or not the left and right subtrees are equal).

However, if you absolutely have to solve it with one function, you could cheat a little. I see two options:

#### Option 1

Local function

```
(defun foo (list)
  (labels ((sum-subtrees (list)
             (cond
               ((null list) 0)
               ((atom list) list)
               (t (+ (car list)
                     (sum-subtrees (cadr list))
                     (sum-subtrees (caddr list)))))))
    (= (sum-subtrees (cadr list))
       (sum-subtrees (caddr list)))))
```

This works by defining a local function to handle the recursive bit- `#'sum-subtrees`- and then just relies on that to compute the final output.

#### Option 2

Multiple value return

```
(defun foo (list)
  (cond
    ((null list) (values t 0))
    ((atom list) (values t list))
    (t (let ((left-sub (nth-value 1 (foo (cadr list))))
             (right-sub (nth-value 1 (foo (caddr list)))))
         (values (= left-sub right-sub)
                 (+ (car list)
                    left-sub
                    right-sub))))))
```

This solution exploits how common lisp functions can return multiple values. Basically, the function returns both the original condition `(= left-subtree right-subtree)` *and* the sum of the tree. Any other code which is expecting just a single value will get the first return value (the condition), so any code that would use this function should not notice the extra return value, but the data is there if you ask for it.

The way we return multiple values is with the values function. In this code, for example, we return `(values t 0)` in the case of list being nil to indicate that its "left and right subtrees" are equal and its sum is 0, and

```
(values (= left-sub right-sub)
        (+ (car list)
           left-sub
           right-sub))
```

to produce the recursive return value.

There are a few ways to get access to the extra return values, but the one used here is `#'nth-value`, which returns the nth value returned instead of the first. That's why, when we make the recursive call to compute the size of the subtree, we use `(nth-value 1 (foo <subtree>))`.

NOTE: Please never actually use that solution for this- multiple value return is very useful and powerful, but in this case it is more confusing than it's really worth.

Comment: your first solution checks to see if the right sub tree and the left sub tree are equal which isn't what the question was for instance

          '(6 (4 (2 1 1) 4) (2 5 (1 1 3))) 

would return true when the last list '(1 1 3) isn't balanced. That code was what my first attempt at it looked like. There are also two other factors your code fails to handle. 

1) there is no more subtree, '(4) would have cadr and caddr called on it and that would return an error since you're adding nil to the result of your previous recursions.

2) "=" only acts on numbers

those were problems i had

Comment: I thought the problem was checking if the sum of the atoms on the left subtree of the given tree were equal to the sum of the atoms on the right subtree of that tree, which my code does calculate. Also, calling `(cdr nil)` works fine-it returns nil, which my code expects and handles. Note, I call `(sum-subtrees (cadr '(4)))`, which returns 0 as `#'sum-subtrees` returns 0 when passed nil. As far as `#'=`, `left-sub` and `right-sub` will never be nil- if there was no left/right subtree those will be 0.